# Authentification error when installing RGEE in RStudio

Tags: r, google-earth-engine, rgee

I am attempting to install the `rgee` package in RStudio, following this tutorial (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgee/vignettes/rgee01.html). I already have Google Cloud and Python installed. When I get to ee_Initialize(), a browser opens and I am able to login to my Google Account to get the authentication token. When I add this token to my R console and hit run, I get the following error:

```
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  It looks like your EE credential has expired. Try running ee_Authenticate() again or clean your credentials ee_clean_user_credentials().
```

I have also tried running ee.Authenticate but get the same error. Has anyone come across a similar error?

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been highlighted on the [Github site](https://github.com/r-spatial/rgee/issues/355) for this package. Multiple people (including me) are having this issue.

See the responses to the question for a workaround. Especially note the response by the author of the rgee package 'csaybar' who details the difficulty in maintaining the package

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I am running in windows machine, R version 4.3.3.

Python version 3.8.18 (conda with reticulate)

It worked when I downgrade the GEE API from version 0.1.391 to 0.1.370 with:

```
library(reticulate)
py_config() # see the name of your conda (python) environment, in my case "r-reticulate". From: "pythonhome: C:/Users/user_name/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate"
reticulate::py_install('earthengine-api==0.1.370', envname='r-reticulate')
```

```
# Check the installation of "earthengine-api" with 
py_list_packages() 
pyl <- py_list_packages()
pyl[pyl$package == "earthengine-api", ]

# check python version with
py_run_string("import sys; print(sys.version)")
```

Source: [github](https://github.com/r-spatial/rgee/issues/353#issuecomment-1983765552)

Answer (score -1):

You were able to solve the problem. The same thing happened to me, so I worked on another machine and so far so good, but at the time of deploying in shiny apps, I get that problem, and so far I have not managed to solve. It seems that it is a problem of the credential that is saved in the C: drive because the same app, I did it in geemap and I had no problems.  But I prefer shiny because I have more affinity with the syntax.